# Shell script execution - Error handling

Tags: c++, qt, shell, qt4

I am designing a gui application using qt creator. In there if i press a button, values from a .csv file gets imported to an sqlite3 database table.

For doing this I have used the QProcess to launch a shell script that contains the commands for importing data.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QProcess process;
    process.startDetached("/bin/sh", QStringList()<< "/home/aj/myscript.sh");
}
```

and myscript.sh for importing is--

```
echo -e '.separator ","\n.import import_table.csv test_table' | sqlite3 testdatabase.db
```

the reason behind this approach is that dot-commands can not be integrated directly to the c++ gui program without creating custom parsing solutions.

Now, this approach (QProcess and shell script) works perfectly well for me. But one bottle neck is it does not offer any error-handling/identification.

For example if the import command stops midway during data retrieval or all the values in .csv are not imported I would not know the problem. Is there any way to know if problem has occurred during importing ??? (redirecting the message via QDebug???)

Comment: Rather than using a script running from a separate process, can you not use Qt's own classes, such as QSqlDatabase and QSqlQuery? http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqlquery.html

Comment: I tried using QSqlDatabase, but the problem is that commands like .import and .separator did not get passed through the query

Comment: Does this help? http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/37026

Comment: thanks, the concept is similar, but in case data import is interrupted then which error log i need to backup in a file ?? the error message of the shell-script ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QProcess has a member function called `exitCode()` which oddly enough returns the exit code of the process.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprocess.html

Finding that answer required a 10-second search in google for the documentation...

Comment: exitcode() is helpful without a doubt but will it retrieve database related errors directly ??? like qDebug can be used to see db.lastError(); Can similar be done with exitcode() ??? it gives out only an int right ???

Comment: if you want to analyse the stderr output of the spawned process, `QProcess` has methods for this too. However, if you're going to start analysing error output then you really should be using an in-process library to talk to the database and not an external script.